# Hash MD5 or SHA256

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For hashing which function  Hash MD5 or SHA256 we should use so that we don't have any duplicates.

I am trying to write a ETL process where we have some dimension tables  which are Slowly changing dimension type 2.
To capture if the data has been updated, will do the following steps.

1. I will capture the hash value for the load.
2. Compare the hash value for the previous and the current load.
3. If the hash value has changed then a new row will be added in the table.
4. The row_active column will be updated to row_active  = 'N' for the old row and will be 'Y' for the new row.

The sample table structure is as follows.

```
Create table EMP
(EMP_NO integer,
EMP_First_name varchar (100),
EMP_last_name varchar (100),
emp_designation_id varchar (10),
emp_add_line_1 varchar (100),
emp_add_line_2 varchar (100),
city varchar(100),
state varchar(100),
country varchar(100),
hash_val varchar(250),
row_active varchar(1)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory neither guarantees that you won’t get duplicates though in practice the chances of this happening are remote. SHA256 is less likely to produce duplicates than MD5 but takes longer to calculate - so up to you which one you use